# How do I read the PE header of a module loaded in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, portable-executable

I'm experimenting with memory access in .NET. At the moment, I have a managed program that starts an **unmanaged** process and retrieves the `BaseAddress` of one of its loaded modules (a DLL). What I would like to do is somehow read the PE header of the loaded module so that I can later retrieve the addresses of its exports.

Unfortunately, I can't find any good information about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) is a good starting point for the PE file format.

You can P/Invoke [ReadProcessMemory](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadProcessMemory.html) from the base address you have to copy the headers into your process.  You'll need to parse the memory you read into the various PE headers.  The first header is the [IMAGE_DOS_HEADER](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER), which will point you to the [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS).  You can then use the [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32) in the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS to find the location of the [IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY) in the binary.