# C# Get/Read DLL Imports Used

Tags: c#, dll, import, get

1. Hey, my question is simple but I can't find a way to do this.

What I try to do is:
I try to get all the DLL Imports and the functions used from an EXE or DLL.

So let's say I make a program with the: SendMessage (DLL Import)
Then the code would manage to read that.

And return like:

**DLL:** user32.dll

**Function:** SendMessage

I have tried using the: Assembly. But no luck getting correct data from it.

(I did look at: [How to programatically read native DLL imports in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571088/how-to-programatically-read-native-dll-imports-in-c)
But didn't get it to work there either, I got 1 import, but nothing more)

Comment: Is this about the about _declspec(dllimport/export) the C++ attribute that tell what a unmanaged library imports/exports. Or the DLLImport attribute in a managed program?

Comment: I'm meaning like this:

[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
public static extern int puts(string c);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure reflection approach

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DumpExports(typeof (string).Assembly);
    }

    public static void DumpExports( Assembly assembly)
    {

        Dictionary<Type, List<MethodInfo>> exports = assembly.GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                                    .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DllImportAttribute), false).Length > 0))
            .GroupBy(method => method.DeclaringType)
            .ToDictionary( item => item.Key, item => item.ToList())
            ;

        foreach( var item in exports )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key.FullName);

            foreach( var method in  item.Value )
            {
                DllImportAttribute attr = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DllImportAttribute), false)[0] as DllImportAttribute;
                Console.WriteLine("\tDLL: {0}, Function: {1}", attr.Value, method.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for :)
It really helped me out. 
Seems I was on the right track, just missed the part: GetMethods

Just another quick thing:
How safe is it to use?
If I "check" a harmful file, will it harm my PC? Or will this only read from the EXE itself and not trigger anything.

Comment: You aren't executing the code or exe, unless someone has managed to find a vulnerability in the .NET reflection engine.

Answer (score 3):

The [DUMPBIN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) program examines the DLL PE Header and lets you determine this info.

I don't know of any C# wrapper but these articles should show you how to examine the header and dump out the exports yourself

- [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)
- [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

As a lateral thought - why not wrap *`dumpbin.exe /exports`* with a .net System.Process call and parse the results?