# How to find out if a game supports DirectX in C#

Tags: c#, directx

does anyone know how to check through the code whether the game uses DirectX or not?

I’m writing an installer for modifications for games in C# and I needed the DirectX checking function to avoid library conflicts.

Thank you!

I tried asking ChatGPT but it gives me some garbage:

```
    static bool GetDirectXVersionFromGame(string gamePath, out string directXVersion)
    {
        directXVersion = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(gamePath);

            string fileVersion = fileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
            if (fileVersion != null)
            {
                directXVersion = fileVersion;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to test at runtime or just looking at the game's files? In the later case, you can browse all .exe and .dll files and check for their dll import https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571088/how-to-programatically-read-native-dll-imports-in-c for all directX main dlls: d3d9.dll, d3d10.dll, d3d11.dll, d3d12.dll. Any import should do but you can also check specific ones: Direct3DCreate9(Ex), D3D10CreateDevice, D3D11CreateDevice, D3D12CreateDevice. Obviously this won't work is the game is packed using techniques like UPX, etc. you'd have to exctract files first.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Ideally, I would just scan the exe.

Comment: Yes, that's what I proposed